# Возможно ли сделать вертикально-вылезающее на нажатие по кнопке колонку в стиле Material Design?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, metro

Пишу программу на winapi. Но проблема в том, что получается она не очень красивой, хоть и функциональной. Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли сделать вертикальную колонку в стиле Metro не использую UWP и XAML? Если можно, не могли бы вы дать пример программы, в которой это сделано?

Comment: Material Design != Metro, разве нет?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что за вертикальную колонку нужно получить. [Вот](http://bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour327.htm) есть пример реализации UI который сделан в стиле Metro. Библиотека BCG платная, по сути это надстройка над MFC. Писать сейчас интерфейс на чистом WinAPI уже никуда не годится (хотя и MFC тоже уже морально устарел, но всё таки ещё живёт).

Comment: @dzhioev перепутал, но суть одна. Сделать приложение в более менее современном стиле